# How to pass a document's ID using Azure CosmoDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a simple CRUD app to learn Azure. I have created a logic app (standard model) and my APIs are designed using the workflow designer. I also have a CosmoDB to hold each object.

My GET API, that gets all the documents, looks like this:

[image]

And my GET API, that gets only one document, looks like this:

[image]

Here is what my CosmosDB looks like with the ID of the item that is successfully return when statically called:

[image]

So what do I need to replace the static ID with, in the `*Document ID` input so that I can pass in different IDs?

I have looked at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/documentdb/#get-a-document-(v2)) and it suggests `documentId`, but when I type this in I get this error:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You should know the `id` you want to retrieve from the flow that feeds into the `Get a document` block (unless it's static). Since you only have a HTTP trigger your `id` should be supplied through that. As example by passing the `id` in the url as query parameter which you then refer to in your Document ID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @404 , posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

" You should know the `id` you want to retrieve from the flow that feeds into the Get a document block (unless it's static). Since you only have a `HTTP trigger` your id should be supplied through that. As example by passing the id in the `url` as query parameter which you then refer to in your `Document ID` field."

Trigger a post request to logic app with `Document ID` in request body.

Try as below:
[image]